# express session doesn't work on firebase function

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js, google-cloud-functions, express-session

Currently, this is my code:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
app.set('views', __dirname+'/views');
app.set('view engine','jsx');
app.engine('jsx', reactViews.createEngine());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(
    session({
        secret:'key',
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        cookie:{
            maxAge: 30000000
        }
    })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session())
```

It works fine when using `app.listen(8080)`, but not on `firebase` functions. When I run the `firebase function`, the `passport.serializeUser` got called but no session was stored.  It shows `req.user` is  undefined. Is there a way to make express-session work on the `firebase` function?

Answer (score 0):

You can safely [disable session support](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/#disable-sessions)

```
passport.authenticate('basic', { session: false })
```